# How can I syncronize simultaneous shots taken with two cameras?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, software, camera-basics

How can I capture two simultaneous shots using two cameras and two cameramen? For example I want to capture one person throwing a frisbee while the other person is chasing it down. I'm not trying to capture both images in the same photo, I want them separate. And the thing is, I'm trying to capture the exact same moments in each still. One camera would have to be the camera shooting away while the other camera is just in position to take the right shots. Any ideas?

Comment: I apologize, but my curiosity is killing me -- why the requirement for simultaneous shots?

Answer (score 9):

If at least the remote camera supports a wired remote release, then you can use the PocketWizard system (or a similar radio trigger -- several support remote camera firing as well as flash triggering) to do the job, plus-or-minus all of those factors that go into shutter lag. If both cameras support wired remote releases and neither needs to be set into any special mode to use the wired remote, then each of the cameras can be used to trigger the other if you want -- but that would probably be a weird experience for both photographers rather than just for the voice-activated tripod guy you're envisioning.

Comment: If there is no wired or wireless trigger facility another option is to capture video in both cameras and find an external way to pick the same moment in each video stream (for example by bringing both cameras together and pointing them at the same synchronising event).